# Consuming json data and displaying it in columns

Tags: jquery, angularjs, json

I want to display the json data like in the image below through angular js.

the json user list

Answer (score 1):

We can use ng-repeat logic over the result and bind it to table

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    (function() {

      angular.module("testApp", ['ui.bootstrap']).controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.userData = undefined;
        $scope.selectedUser = undefined;
        $http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=30&nat=US').then(function(response) {
          $scope.userData = response.data;
        });
        $scope.selectUser = function(usr){
          $scope.selectedUser=usr;
        };
      }]);


    }());
  </script>
  <style>
    .userInfo{
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      margin-top:10px;
      padding:5px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .userInfo:hover{
      background: #ccc;
    }
    
    .profile{
      padding-left: 0px;
      padding-right: 0px;
    }
    .ellipsis{
      white-space: nowrap; 
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body ng-app="testApp">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <form name="commonForm">
      <div ng-hide="selectedUser">
        <div class="col-sm-4 userInfo" ng-repeat="user in userData.results" ng-click="selectUser(user)" >
            <img class="col-sm-4 profile" ng-src="{{user.picture.medium}}"/>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="ellipsis"><b>{{user.name.first}} {{user.name.last}}</b></div>
                <div class="ellipsis">{{user.email}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      
      
      <div ng-show="selectedUser">
        <button ng-click="selectedUser = undefined">Go Back</button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <img class="col-sm-4 profile" ng-src="{{selectedUser.picture.large}}"/>
        
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="first">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first" ng-model="selectedUser.name.first">
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="last">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last" ng-model="selectedUser.name.last">
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Login:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" ng-model="selectedUser.login.username" disabled>
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" ng-model="selectedUser.email">
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dob">Date of Birth:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dob" ng-model="selectedUser.dob">
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nat">Nationality:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nat" ng-model="selectedUser.nat">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: bro can we get this in a layout i mean in 3 column grid layout

Comment: Both ways are possible. Instead of displaying data in a table you want it in 3 column grid layout?

Comment: updated code snippet. Please check it in fullpage view

Comment: yes got it and bro can we get the specific users data in a other page  when we click on a particular user ? https://imgur.com/a/lMVCn

Comment: like when a user is clicked on we display his image and the rest of the image like the image I have attached

Comment: yes it is possible. THere are two ways to achieve this. 1. Using ngRoute and 2. Show and hide pages. I always recommended to use ngRoute

Comment: i am actually new to angular js

Comment: I can show it in the same page using show/hide option

Comment: that should be fine if it's the same page too.